# diH2O, dH2O, and DI H2O. What do they mean?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, water, terminology

What do $\ce{diH_2O, dH_2O}$, and $\ce{DI H_2O}$ mean?

I'm not asking for a description of deionized water and distilled water. I'm asking what the three abbreviations/formulas mean.

In other words, I'm asking someone to fill in the blanks below.

- $\ce{diH_2O = \_\_\_\_\_}$
- $\ce{dH_2O = \_\_\_\_\_}$
- $\ce{DI H_2O = \_\_\_\_\_}$

Comment: * diH2O = ***d*e*i*onized water**
* dH2O = ***d*istilled water**
* DI H2O = ***d*e*i*onized water**

Comment: Thanks @CurtF. I found a book that referred to diH2O as distilled, not deionized water. Is there no commonly accepted standard, or is this just a fluke reference I found? https://books.google.com/books?id=KZateS3byQgC&pg=PA8&lpg=PA8&dq=distilled+water+%22dih2o%22&source=bl&ots=bj1HcMCZY-&sig=p10fa2fkSHtIYrdpCJPJorc_XXM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja2azhgv7KAhVMxGMKHRp1AcYQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=distilled%20water%20%22dih2o%22&f=false

Comment: I don't think there is a commonly accepted standard.  If I had to guess, I'd say more often than not di$\ce{H2O}$ is used to mean deionized water, but I've nothing but my own experience to base that on.  Sorry for the lack of references.  Also, `ddH2O` is a common abbreviation that used to mean "double-distilled water" but now is used to refer to highly pure water produced by laboratory purification systems such as those from milliQ or similar.

Comment: As Curt F. indicates, what they stand for and what they are in practice are two different things. In practice, the four abbreviations "mean" the same thing: high purity water. If there's some practical difference between distilled, double-distilled and deionized water that means one is suitable and the other is not, you'll normally get a more extensive description of the minimal performance and purity characteristics necessary for the application.

Comment: Hello community. Can we not remove the "In other words" part of my question? I know it is redundant. I'd like to state it twice in slightly different ways. Sorry if that irks those out there who like conciseness.

Comment: OK. this has become a challenge. Rolling back for the fourth time. I'll eventually wear out.

Comment: I have rolled this back and locked it for the time being.  Rather than taking up people's time in this fashion, this would have better been addressed on Meta rather than as a "war."  The bottom line is that it's much better to keep questions more conceptual rather than about specific homework examples.

Comment: A meta discussion about the edits to this question can be found here: http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/3467/7951

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think there is a commonly accepted standard. If I had to guess, I'd say more often than not $\mathrm{di}\ce{H2O}$ is used to mean deionized water, but I've nothing but my own experience to base that on. Sorry for the lack of references. Also, $\mathrm{dd}\ce{H2O}$ is a common abbreviation that used to mean "double-distilled water" but now is used to refer to highly pure water produced by laboratory purification systems such as those from Milli-Q or similar.

- $\mathrm{DI}\ce{H2O}$ = deionized water
- $\mathrm{di}\ce{H2O}$ = deionized water

  - Such water is often available from centralized water purification systems in buildings that host many chemical laboratories.  It isn't as pure as "$\mathrm{dd}\ce{H2O}$" (see below) but is subtanstially more pure than tap water.
- $\mathrm{d}\ce{H2O}$ = distilled water
- $\mathrm{dd}\ce{H2O}$ = doubly distilled water
- $\mathrm{mq}\ce{H2O}$ = Milli-Q water

  - The brand name of a popular type of water purifier that gives purity similar to $\mathrm{dd}\ce{H2O}$